# Apply fuzzywuzzy to a pandas df with lots of names

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I have a df that looks something like this:

```
Name                |Address | State | Phone | Website
--------------------------------------------------------
agua calienta       |etc etc etc
agua caliente       |
blue lake           |
blue lake club      |
artichoke           |
artichoke club      |
creek club          |
cahuilla creek      |
cahuilla crek resort|
taj club            |
taj mahal           |
taj mahal club hotel|
```

and so on.
The name is a resort/hotel name, however there are a lot of typos and variations of names in the data. 
Using Levensteins distance and the `fuzzywuzzy` package, I was able to get all similar names doing

```
choices = df['Name'].unique()

def get_ratio(row):
    name = row['Name']
    return fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name, 'agua caliente')

df[df.apply(get_ratio, axis = 1) > 60]
```

Then I could hypothetically rename all the names with a score higher than 60 by using

```
df.loc[df.apply(get_ratio, axis=1) > 75, "Name"] = "Agua Caliente"
```

However this only works for the 1 name that I used.

Is there a way to apply this to all the names which are similar?
For example after applying I would get something that looks like the following:

```
Name                |Address | State | Phone | Website
--------------------------------------------------------
Agua Caliente       |etc etc etc
Agua Caliente       |
Blue Lake Club      |
Blue Lake Club      |
Artichoke Club      |
Artichoke Club      |
Creek Club          |
Cahuilla Resort     |
Cahuilla Resort     |
Taj Mahal           |
Taj Mahal           |
Taj Mahal           |
```

I have a reference list/table of all the possible Names.  How would I loop through and apply the get_ratio function to go through the list and return all similar names on the list?

Answer (score 0):

You would need an exhaustive list of the correct names.

```
taj club            
taj mahal           
taj mahal club hotel
```

You would need a reference table (or a list of rules) with the correct names. In the example above, the reference table field would need to be `Taj Mahal` and not `taj club` or `taj mahal club hotel`.

Based on that, you would use the approaches that you mentioned i.e. `fuzzywuzzy` and the Levenshtein distance. Unfortunately, without knowing the correct reference ('Taj Mahal', in this case), there isn't an exact way to apply a function to guess the correct reference. It is a rule based approach that you would need to take.

**Additional**

Per the comments, you would need to create a function that compares it to your reference table and gets the score and then returns the name of the correct city.

Example:

```
def replace_name(name_of_city: str):
    #
    # Extra code to look up your reference table
    # and find the correct city name (with the lowest or highest
    # score) depending on your methodology

    return name_of_correct_city
```

then map this function to the entire `Name` column in your dataframe like this:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(lambda x: replace_name(x))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can make a reference table, my question is if I can apply the function to everything all at once, so instead of having to return each name individually, it returns all of the names that are similar on the reference list.
For example for Taj Mahal, it would return everything like it, and then clean and replace it.  
I will edit my question to make it a bit more clear

Comment: @Dasax121 Thank you for making your question clearer. I assumed that you didn't have a reference table as it wasn't mentioned. I'll edit my answer. In short, once you have a function with all the rules, you can use the `map` function on the column in your dataframe and it will apply it to the entire column.

Comment: @Dasax121 : I edited my answer to answer your question. Let me know if it makes things clearer.